# systemd never perform StartLimitAction (reboot) after service fails

Tags: systemd-unit

I facing the same problem (which is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908660/systemd-always-have-a-service-running-and-reboot-if-service-stops-more-than-x), having following service. I made my service failing every minute (means it does not send notify signal) so service is restarted but it never reboot the system. Any Idea?

```
[Service]
#Type=simple
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
#ExecStartPre=/sbin/modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
ExecStart=/usr/java/default/bin/java -Xms150m -Xmx150m \
-Djava.library.path=/home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/build/lib:/usr/local/src/openalpr/src/bindings/java:/home/pi/compile/raspicam-0.1.3/src/jni/:/home/pi/co
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.16.16.139 \
-jar /home/pi/garageSystem.jar eu /home/pi/alpr.conf /usr/local/src/openalpr/runtime_data/ /home/pi/conf/

Restart=on-failure
#Restart=always
RestartSec=1
WatchdogSec=60s


#OnFailure=systemd-reboot

StartLimitIntervalSec=5m
StartLimitBurst=1
StartLimitAction=force-reboot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Additional system info

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.14-v7+ #977 SMP Mon Mar 13 18:25:19 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemd --version
systemd 215
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ -SECCOMP -APPARMOR
```

**Update:**

I have probably found solution for my case, when I need to reboot device, when service fail. Since systemd from version 213 https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-commits/2014-May/006228.html) supports `FailureAction=reboot` , which works the same as `StartLimitAction` but on every fail = thats what I wanted. But it nothing changes, that `StartLimitAction` does not  work. Do u think, it is a bug?

Comment: Have you used `systemd-analyze verify ./path/to/your/file.service` to see if there any warnings or errors with your service file?

Answer (score 1):

According to `man systemd.unit`, the correct value for `StartLimitAction=` is `reboot-force`. But you have used `force-reboot`, which is not a valid option.

`systemd` will report this problem if you use `systemd-analyze verify`:

```
systemd-analyze verify ./path/to/your/file.service
[/etc/systemd/system/test.service:4] Failed to parse failure action specifier, ignoring: force-reboot
```

Comment: Yes, thats correct! But i was also using only reboot command. but I will verify it

Comment: So i have change it to  StartLimitIntervalSec=5m    StartLimitBurst=1
 StartLimitAction=reboot-force, do nothing, also if StartLimitAction is set to "reboot".   Running "systemd-analyze verify garage.service"  gives output "Unknown operation 'verify'."  I have checked manual and there is not such commend

Comment: Just one more question, is there any "internal" log of systemd where is written, what is it performing? I mean, that if there is something what could tell me StartLimitBurst  was reached and StartLimitAction  is performed?

Comment: You can use `journalctl`  to read the systemd journal. I don't know what it will log about those actions. You'll have to check /etc/systemd/journald.conf` to confirm the systemd journald logs are persisting through reboots.

Comment: If my answer is correct, please upvote and accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Answer is correct, but problem is not solved as StartLimitAction is still not invoked....-(

Comment: I can't help further, your systemd version is rather out of date. If you wondering if there was a bug in systemd, you could test the syntax in a virtual machine with a newer version of `systemd`. It seems your version of `systemd` also lacks the helpful `verify` subcommand for `systemd-analyze`

Comment: OK, i will try to update it, but before posting I have performed all update commands, so I will try to update it to the latest one and return back. But thank you anyway.